# Laravel BroadcastService Provider error for live website

Tags: laravel, vue.js

If I uncomment the line inside config/app.php

```
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

To

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

it gives 500 Error and stops the website from loading

I had set broadcastdriver to pusher

and also checked all broadcast::routes();

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the logs of your application (see `storage/logs`) to see the detailed errors that are causing the 500 error. Most likely it's that your environment hasn't got the correct credentials for a Pusher account.